# how to start to play music in locked screen in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using `UILocalNotification` to alert the user if app not running and `MPMusicPlayerController` to play iPod music and `MPMoviePlayerController` to play radio stream url.

According to Apple doc:
 if iphone is locked and device receives local notification then it will play 30 second sound and when user  slides the slider then it will take app in foreground and two scenarios take place

1. If App not running then calls method

   `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`
2. If App already running then calls method -

   `(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notify`

and i can perform my task in these methods.

Problem :
I need my application to be able to play my sound (it may be iPod music or stream url but not local notification sound for 30 sec) when the iPhone is locked and local notification  received and app is running in foreground.

Reference App :
"Alarm Clock HD" and other apps also available in app store are working fine in this way but these are not able to play alarm when app is running in background (i could not understand why???)

I also tried  [how-to-prevent-iphone-from-deep-sleeping](http://blog.marcopeluso.com/2009/08/23/how-to-prevent-iphone-from-deep-sleeping/) :

which prevent the iPhone from deep sleep by playing silent music periodically but how to notify app that notification has received so start to play "actual music" ? And how to start to play new music?

Comment: @DineshPatel i know i can use player to play audio, even i am using but problem is that when screen is locked  i don't have any control to my app then how to notify to app that notification has received so app should start to play audio.

Comment: Hi Manju, did you find any solution for your problem? if yes, please suggest me, how can i do it.

Answer (score 5):

@manju sorry i got late but it work for you.

```
 selectedDate = [timePicker date];
```

it is selectedDate date object,at this time your notification will came.
   `[NSDate date]` by this you can find current time. and find different both time via.

```
 NSTimeInterval timeDifference =  [ selectedDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Now when your are schedule your notification then .write this code

```
 UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
 UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;

 NSTimer  *backgroundTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeDifference    target:self  selector:@selector(backgroundTask) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    }];

    -(void)backgroundTask
    {
        NSLog(@"Here you can play song via player ");
       }
```

Don't forgot to add in app.infolist

UIApplication BackgroundMode  Audio 
it will solve your problem , play song when device is lock.

Comment: -(void)backgroundTask called when notification received even in background but i written a code snipped to play audio using AVAudioplayer which starts to play audio in foreground but not in background. I already set"required background mode" to "play audio"      in plist

Comment: My code-  -(void)backgroundTask
{
    NSLog(@"Here you can play song via player ");
    NSURL *audioFileLocationURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"HeadspinLong" withExtension:@"caf"];
    NSError *error=nil;
    delegate.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileLocationURL error:&error];
    [delegate.audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];
    [delegate.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [delegate.audioPlayer play];
}  In foreground it prints log as well as start to play audio but in background it displays only log, do not play audio

Comment: Hi Dinesh, i have same issue as manju had, log print but music does not start in background.

Answer (score 2):

use `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` for audio session. Check audio session programming guide  [**here**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH1-SW1)

Comment: i already have seen this link but could not understand how to notify app that notification has received so start to play music

Comment: how to call (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notify method in locked screen without sliding slider

Comment: I thought your question was how to play music in locked screen?

Comment: i m newbie to iOS sorry could not clarify my problem, actually i want to play music(from ipod library and streaming url) on receiving UILocalNotification when app is running in foreground and iphone is locked like an alarm