# Alarm Clock AVPlayer

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, avplayer, alarm

I have to create an alarm clock app. I use `UILocalNotifications`, but I want to start an audio stream as alarm. The `UILocalNotifications` are working. But If I put the play (`[player play]`) method in the `didReceiveLocalNotification`, it isnt going to play!

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to do that now... But I will post it asap!

Comment: Ps this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222054/how-to-start-to-play-music-in-locked-screen-in-iphone

Comment: Thanks for that! But only the log is showing and the music isn't going to play...

Comment: Which part do you need of my code? Now I use the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222054/how-to-start-to-play-music-in-locked-screen-in-iphone.